# How to get a halide buffer with data on GPU?

Tags: gpu, halide

I'm new to halide. Now I have a pointer which points to data on GPU. I want to get a halide buffer from this pointer without copying data. I have searched a lot and found this [/halidebuffer-on-gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822087/halidebuffer-on-gpu) . It says using Buffer::device_wrap_native will be helpful. And I have read the docs of it[Buffer::device_wrap_native](http://halide-lang.org/docs/class_halide_1_1_runtime_1_1_buffer.html#a5eab3a0f803010e2bbe998c5ba222fbe)But I'm little confused about what value should I pass to device_interface? [docs of device_interface](http://halide-lang.org/docs/structhalide__device__interface__t.html) don't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

For device_interface you want to pass either halide_cuda_device_interface(), or halide_opencl_device_interface(), or similar. These methods are all defined in HalideRuntime*.h. Here's the full list:

```
HalideRuntimeCuda.h: halide_cuda_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeD3D12Compute.h: halide_d3d12compute_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeHexagonDma.h: halide_hexagon_dma_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeHexagonHost.h: halide_hexagon_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeMetal.h: halide_metal_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeOpenCL.h: halide_opencl_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeOpenGL.h: halide_opengl_device_interface();
HalideRuntimeOpenGLCompute.h: halide_openglcompute_device_interface();
```